# How to bind Enum to routes static parameter

Tags: java, playframework

How do I bind a enum from my Model to a static parameter in my routes definition?

Example (made up):

**Model:**

```
class User (..)
{
    public static enum TYPES { Default, Admin, Editor, Visitor }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
class Users (..)
{
    public static void create(long parentUserId, User.TYPES type)
    {
       (..)
    }
}
```

**Routes:**

```
GET     /user/{parentUserId}/create/editor  Users.create(type:User.TYPES.Editor)
```

**View template:**

```
<a href="@{Users.create(user.id, 'Editor')}">create editor</a>
```

or

```
<a href="@{Users.create(user.id, User.TYPES.Editor)}">create editor</a>
```

Both don't work. How should I set this up?

Comment: Since a have an object instance of the type User in my render values, I also tried: `__user.TYPES.Editor` which actually gave me this `Exception raised was MissingPropertyException : No such property: TYPES for class: models.User. `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I've tested this with working environment.

The following works:

Template:

```
  <a href="@{Application.create(5, models.Game.GameType.Succession.name())}">create editor</a>
```

Route:

```
 GET     /user/{parentUserId}/create/{type}/editor  Application.create
```

Controller:

```
  public static void create(long parentUserId, Game.GameType type)
    { ... }
```

The route with a predefined parameter doesn't work:

```
GET     /user/{parentUserId}/editor  Application.create(type:models.Game.GameType.Succession.name())
```

It will always set `type` to `null`

Comment: No luck; `@{Users.create(user.id, models.User.TYPES.Editor)}` gave me `No route able to invoke action Users.create was found.` with route `GET /user/{parentUserId}/create/editor Users.create(type:models.User.TYPES.Editor)`; Too bad :'-(

Comment: `@{Users.create(user.id).add('type', models.User.TYPES.Editor)}` this worked!!

Comment: I meant, it gave no error (thought it worked for a second), but it doesn't work propertly :( the line in the routes does match ALL types :(

Comment: From console/logger: `20:16:11,468 WARN  ~ Ignoring type:models.User.TYPES.Editor(static params must be specified as key:'value',...)` :-(

Comment: Yeah, and extract your enum of your class and make an external enum : UserTypeEnum. Way easier and make a lot more sens than including it in anthor class.

Comment: It's not valid to put "Application.create" in the routes file. You'll get "missing arguments for method create in class Application;"